# How to force clion 2016.3.2 to use system cmake?

Tags: cmake, clion

I am using CLion 2016.3.2 and it is delivered with cmake 3.6.
Many of my libraries and also the external libraries (gtest, opencv) use some commands(eg `find_package_handle_standard_args`) which changed its invocation api. Thus, configuring a project from withing clion fails.
When I configure the same project using my system cmake (3.0), everything works fine.

So the question: Is there a way to force clion to use the installed cmake?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

File -> Settings... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains -> CMake executable

Then set the custom path.

Note that I do not know if this will solve your specific problem.